# Resizing UserControl on ParentChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms UserControl that I want to resize when it's added to the form (In design time), when debugging, I see that for some reason Visual Studio designer generates an Extra OnResize event after the ParentChanged event with a wrong size (200x100), I want my size set on ParentChanged event to be kept unchanged, is there a workaround for this?

```
//Sample class that reproduces the error, this usercontrol appears as a 200x100 
//control when added to a windows forms designer rather than 1024x768
public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl
{
    public TestUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you rely on Docking and/or Anchoring instead of resizing manually?

Comment: It's probably possible, but would require me to rethink my design because other sibling controls are not docked, and I wanna do it in ParentChanged event because I use the parent's properties to calculate, size, location and custom properties